# Wordpress site slow at random intervals

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have a WordPress site hosted in a server. I also verified the server configs everything is perfect. No space or ram issues.

When I start to load my site URL. In my networks tab, I see that the first request was "instant-loan/" which took 1min and rest all requests come faster after that. Ofcourse they loaded from cache in the image I shared but if I open in incognito also the rest of the requests are in miliseconds. This happens in all pages,

[image]

What could be the issue here? I have been searching for a possible cause for a very long time.

I have performed a site performance test in google insights and GT. They both gave the same below results:

1. Page loading: 35sec.
2. They only say to optimize images and js content.
3. The total page size is 6mb.
4. 214 requests are beeing processed.

**[NEW EDIT]**

Below is the performance result. It shows a lot of idle time and js image rendering seems to happen quite fast. A max of 4 sec to render, load the site. Thus I assume there is something wrong with the server. I have minified CSS and JS. Also, use compressed images only. Is this because of any mysql connection issue ?? Has anyone faced it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using tools like GTmetrix or Pingdom to identify what slows down your site? Provide a URL if you need help with that.

Comment: I would love to provide URL but we are still in the development stage so sorry abt that. I have checked in google insights. They gave a score of 1. It takes 30s to load the page. GT also says 35sec. Which is way high. They only say to optimise images and js content. Total page size is 6mb and 214 requests are beeing processed.

Comment: In GTmetrix, there is a list of recommendations to improve your PageSpeed and YSlow scores, and then there is Waterfall that tells you how long each resource took to load, this allows you to identify the plugins that're slowing down your site. I can better assist you if I can take a look at the GTmetrix report. We can do this in private if you're still in the development stage.

Comment: Actually, Both the metric sites suggest compressing of js files and remove the redundant js includes. But even after that under the network tab, it says 11sec for just one PHP file to load. Is this because of a slow server ??

Comment: Example: an image takes 900ms to load but If I load the same file separately in new tab its coming faster